# Divide a value in a Dataframe column with the previous value in the same column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, division

I'm working with pandas and dataframe, and I have a simple question:

I have a dataframe (let's call it `df`) like this:

| index | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 | 2 | 5 |
| 1 | 4 | 7 | 6 |
| 2 | 2 | 4 | 8 |

i need to make an additional column `D`, in with I must have the ratio of the `C` Value with the precedent one: first value of the column should be 5/0 (where impossible to divide, NAN or 0 will be good), second value should be 6/5, third value should be 8/6.

I can't manage to make it work. I'm trying to apply lambda function but without success when it comes to use the "previous value". (`.shift()` is not working)

```
df['D'] = df['C'].apply(lambda x:x['C']/ ???   )
```

Is this the right road, or there is something I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) instead of `apply`:

```
df['D'] = df['C'] / df['C'].shift()

# index  A  B  C         D
# 0      3  2  5       NaN
# 1      4  7  6  1.200000
# 2      2  4  8  1.333333
```

Optionally chain [`Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) if you want 0 instead of NaN:

```
df['D'] = df['C'].div(df['C'].shift()).fillna(0)

# index  A  B  C         D
# 0      3  2  5  0.000000
# 1      4  7  6  1.200000
# 2      2  4  8  1.333333
```

Comment: Thank you ;-))))))

Comment: done ;-) sorry was my first post and didn't knew how to ;-)